# how to set an alert dialog to be shown correctly?

Tags: android, android-activity

I have a button in my app and I want to show a Alert Dialog when I press that button. I tried to do it but didn't work.I'll be tankful if anyone can help me.
here's my code

```
   cancelBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            AlertDialog.Builder builder=new AlertDialog.Builder(getApplicationContext());

            builder.setMessage("unsaved content.are you sure you want to abort operation ?");

            builder.setPositiveButton("yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    clearAll();

                }


            });


            builder.setNegativeButton("no",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                     dialog.cancel();

                }
            } );


            builder.create();
            builder.show();


        }
    });
```

Comment: Whats the error you are getting? Post logs if you are getting error

Comment: there is no error but the dialog didn't show up .

Comment: Did you check whether the code is actually called?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it needs to be

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MyActivity.this);
```

instead of

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getApplicationContext());
```

where `MyActivity` is the `Activity` where you have written this code.

Also, you forgot to add

```
builder.setTitle("Title");
```